Name for a function on square matrices that is multilinear and alternating in the columns?
In the introductory linear algebra course I'm teaching, we teach students about the vectors space of functions on square matrices that are multilinear and alternating in the columns. Then we eventually prove that the determinant is the unique such function that maps the identity matrix to 1.
Are there any reasonable names for this class of functions in the literature? I was thinking of using something like "quasi-determinant" or "quasi-volume function", but I'd prefer to use a more standard term if it exists.
Obviously from the point of view of exterior algebra these are basically alternating top exterior forms in disguise, but we don't mention exterior algebra at all in the course.

I remember that in my linear algebra course, these were simply called "determinant maps" and when it was shown that there is only one such map, we started calling it the determinant map.

I also think it can be convenient to call them "determinant maps" (in fact at times even for vector-valued alternating multilinear maps).
